# do-release-upgrade fails on BeagleBone Black runnig Ubuntu 14.04 with encoding error

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, arm

```
# do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1230 kB]                                                   
Fetched 1230 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
authenticate 'wily.tar.gz' against 'wily.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'wily.tar.gz'

Zwischenspeicher wird gelesen



Ein schwerwiegender Fehler ist aufgetreten 

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py", line 142, in _handleException
"\n".join(lines))
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py", line 177, in error
print(twrap(msg))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/wily", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 240, in main
if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1837, in run
return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1652, in fullUpgrade
self._view.updateStatus(_("Checking package manager"))
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d3h4k3i1/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py", line 156, in updateStatus
print(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens if LANG is set to de_DE.UTF-8.

This does not happen if export LANG=en is set before the upgrade.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The following is probably the problem `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)`, which is the character `ü`. A [similar bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-clone/+bug/1309447) was filed a while ago that seems to be fixed. You can file a new bug report similar to that one explaining your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I agree - it is similar to the reported bug. I will create a bug-report